# How can ı acces array items in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Hi i have an array like this;
Var MyArray:[{title:"test title" price:34553}]
How can ı acces title name

I tried MyArray.title but it returms undefinded how can ı solve this

Comment: you should find a basic js tutorial, `:` is wrong it should be `=`, then is `MyArray[0].title`, arrays use indexes

Comment: SO is not a site to teach you programming. Grab a javascript beginners tutorial which will help you with your first steps

Comment: also read the documentation for basic operations and examples: [MDN: Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [MDN: Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```js
MyArray[index].property
```